# Django: with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm kind of new to django. Been working with it for a while, but still do really silly mistakes all the time. This one though, I seem to have a hard time figuring out... Because I'm sorta new to this I'm not very good at explaining my problem, but here goes...

Error message complains about this bit in template:

```
{% url privblog object.id %}
```

urls.py extract:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'privblog.views.privblog_detail', name="privblog"),)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import PrivBlog
from blog.models import Blog
from django.template import RequestContext

def privblog_detail(request, object_id=None):
    pblog_detail_object = PrivBlog.objects.filter(id=object_id)
    pblog_recent_object = PrivBlog.objects.all()[:5]
    tblog_recent_object = Blog.objects.all()[:5]
    context = {'pblog_detail_object': pblog_detail_object,
        'pblog_recent_object': pblog_recent_object,
        'tblog_recent_object': tblog_recent_object,
        }
    return render_to_response('privblog/privblog_detail.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the beginning of the error states "Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'privblog'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an object called object in your context:

```
{% url privblog object.id %}
```

Should be

```
{% url privblog pblog_detail_object.id %}
```

You might also be having trouble here:

```
return render_to_response('privblog/privblog_detail.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

I've never invoked render_to_response that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this changed nothing I'm afraid. Same error is thrown.

Comment: Which is strange.. The thing you point out is after all a very obvious error after all.

Comment: Try "privblog", also try removing the URL line and printing {{pblog_detail_object.id}} to make sure you actually have it in your template.

Comment: If you by "try 'privblog'" mean I should write for example {{privblog.id}}, then that didn't work. I also tried to print using {{pblog_detail_object.id}} and your suspicions were correct. Nothing got printed so it seems it never reaches the template at all.

Comment: PrivBlog.objects.filter(id=object_id) will return an array with your object in - not the object itself.  Try PrivBlog.objects.get(id=object_id) instead.

Comment: Of course! I even knew that some place in the back of my head. Thanks for pulling it back forward! This fixed the problem!:)